# The desired capacity of an EC2 AutoScaling group is changed when setting the Capacity Provider Strategy and scaling out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to do AutoScaling on ECS on EC2.
When I configured a capacity provider for the cluster and set the service's computing option to the capacity provider strategy, it scaled out successfully upon deployment.
However, the desired capacity for the EC2 AutoScaling group was originally set to 2, but when checked during scale-out, the desired capacity is set to 4.

The original AutoScaling group settings

```
Desired capacity: 2
Minimum 2
Maximum 4
```

[image]
Auto scaling group settings after scale-out

```
Desired capacity:4
Minimum 2
Maximum 4
```

[image]

When the desired capacity was changed, I had to manually reset it back to the original setting, perhaps it will scale in over time?
At any rate, I had to wait 3 minutes after the capacity was changed to 4 to manually change it.

I checked the container instances, and after scaling in, there was a container instance with zero running tasks, but I waited for 10 minutes and it continued to exist without scaling out.